# Unity saving inputfield

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, nullreferenceexception

I am making a 2D platformer where I want the users inputted name to hover over there character.
[This is what the menu screen looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWFRd.png)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class set_usernames : MonoBehaviour {

    public InputField name;
    public InputField second_name;

    private string Bader_input_name;
    private string Dwarf_input_name;

    public void updatename(string name){

    }
    public void setget()
    {
        //Debug.Log (name.text);
        Bader_input_name = name.text;
        Dwarf_input_name = second_name.text;

        //Application.loadedLevel("game");
        Debug.Log ("name was " + Bader_input_name);
        Debug.Log ("name was " + Dwarf_input_name);
        SceneManager.LoadScene ("map_select");
    }
}
```

[This is the error message I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUoYe.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Basically what that means is that you are trying to access an object that's not instantiated. I have no idea how are you trying to access the input but the easiest way is to make two `public` inputs in your `UIController` drag and drop them in Unity and access the `Text` property of input objects like so: `myInput.Text`.